# Mission with Javascript :)

Tags: javascript, windows, html-helper

Good afternoon everyone, I have a problem with javascript.

I was assigned as a task to make a box that changes color when clicking on the page, I was doing my code but I managed to make the box but not change color.

I use Eventlistener because i want to repeat the change color.

Idk what is bad in my code i see alot of forums but nothing help.

I hope you can help me, thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<html><head>
  <title> Cuadro cambia color // By Abraham Gonzalez </title>
</head>

<script>


  function myBody(){
      var myBody;
      myBody = document.getElementById("myBody");
      myBody.addEventListener("click", btnRojoClic)
      ctx.fillStyle = rgb[Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)];
      
  }

  function btnRojoClic(){
    var myBody;
    myBody = document.getElementById("myBody")
    myBody.style.color = "red"

  }
  
</script>

<body id="myBody"> 

 <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
 <script>



 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


  
 var posicion = 0;    
 var tamano = 0;
    
 setInterval(function () {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    ctx.fillRect(posicion,0 , tamano, tamano);
    
    posicion++;
    tamano++;
    
    if (posicion > 400){
        posicion = 0;
        tamano = 0;
    }
}, 30);



</script></body></html>
```

Comment: There are some issues that prevents this from working. First, the function myBody() doesn't get called. It also have a variable with same name, that can't be good. Besides, you are only changing the color of the body (not even the backgroundColor) so it won't have an effect on the box. For that to happen you would need to set the fillstyle like ctx.fillStyle = "red";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things werent correct:

- You never calling myBody()
- myBody was a function and a var
- rgb was undefined

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cuadro cambia color // By Abraham Gonzalez</title>
  </head>

  <body id="myBody">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  </body>

  <script>
    function myBody() {
      var myBodyt = document.getElementById('myBody');
      myBodyt.addEventListener('click', btnRojoClic);
    }

    function btnRojoClic() {
      console.log('clickkeked');
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.fillStyle = "#"+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    }

    myBody();
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var posicion = 0;
    var tamano = 0;

    setInterval(function () {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
      ctx.fillRect(posicion, 0, tamano, tamano);

      posicion++;
      tamano++;

      if (posicion > 400) {
        posicion = 0;
        tamano = 0;
      }
    }, 30);
  </script>
</html>
```

**Edit** only change color when the square is clicked. You cannot add an event listener directly on the rectangle (fillRect) but you can do it on the canvas. When there's a click, check if the event click position (x,y) is on the square (checkCollision ()) . If so change the color.
Note: the square() isn't necessary and can be replaced by a class + the functions (specially render) inside square() are responsible to draw the rect with the given context.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cuadro cambia color // By Abraham Gonzalez</title>
  </head>

  <body id="myBody">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  </body>

  <script>
    function btnRojoClic() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.fillStyle = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    }
    // you cann also use a class instead, the main idea is to check if the click event position was on the square surface. 
    function square() {
      let position = 0;
      let tamano = 0;
      const increasePosition = () => {
        position;
      };
      const increaseSize = () => {
        tamano++;
      };
      const getPosition = () => {
        return position;
      };
      const getTamano = () => {
        return tamano;
      };
      const reset = () => {
        position = 0;
        tamno = 0;
      };
      const move = () => {
        increasePosition();
        increaseSize();
        if (position > 400) {
          reset();
        }
      };
      const render = (context) => {
        ctx.fillRect(position, 0, tamano, tamano);
      };
      return {
        move,
        render,
        getPosition,
        getTamano,
        reset
      };
    }
    /**
     * Get cursor position relativly to canvas 
     */
    const getCursorPosition = (canvas, event) => {
      const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
      const y = event.clientY - rect.top;
      return { x, y };
    };
    /**
     * Check if there is a collision (click position overlap square position) 
     * */
    const checkCollision = (canvas, ev, square) => {
      const { x, y } = getCursorPosition(canvas, ev);
      if (
        x >= square.getPosition() &&
        x <= square.getPosition() + square.getTamano() &&
        y >= square.getPosition() &&
        y <= square.getPosition() + square.getTamano()
      ) {
        canvas.getContext('2d').fillStyle =
          '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
      }
    };

    mySquare = square();

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.addEventListener('click', (ev) =>
      checkCollision(canvas, ev, mySquare)
    );

    setInterval(function () {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
      mySquare.move();
      mySquare.render();
    }, 30);
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: works except that you can click anywhere, even on the background and it will change the color